# I can alter a struct member from one location but not from the other

Tags: c, pointers, struct, member

I am trying to implement a linked list in C - starting simple, with one list containing one node. However, I stumble upon some issues when trying to add data to the node. Here's my implementation thus far:

```
struct mylist_node {
  int data;
};

struct mylist {
  struct mylist_node *head_pt;
};

void mylist_init(struct mylist* l){
    struct mylist_node head_node;
    head_node.data = 5; //First try
    l->head_pt = &head_node;
    l->head_pt->data = 5; //Second try
};
```

And my main method:

```
int main()
{
    struct mylist ml, *ml_pointer;
    ml_pointer = &ml;
    mylist_init(ml_pointer);

    printf("%d\n", ml_pointer->head_pt->data);
    ml_pointer->head_pt->data = 4;
    printf("%d\n", ml_pointer->head_pt->data);

    return 0;
}
```

This should print out

```
5
4
```

If my knowledge of pointers is correct. However, it prints out

```
0
4
```

As you can see I try to set the node data twice within the mylist_init method. Neither appears to be working - meanwhile, writing to and reading from it from my main method works just fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `mylist_init`, you're storing the address of a local variable in the struct pointed to by `l`.  That variable goes out of scope when the function returns, so the memory it occupied is no longer valid, and thus the pointer that previously pointed to it now points to an invalid location.  Returning the address of a local variable a dereferencing that address invokes undefined behavior.

Your function needs to allocate memory dynamically using `malloc` so the memory will still be valid when the function returns.

```
void mylist_init(struct mylist* l){
    struct mylist_node *head_node = malloc(sizeof(*head_node));
    l->head_pt = head_node;
    l->head_pt->data = 5; 
};
```

Also, don't forget to `free` the memory when you're done using it.

Comment: Aaah, that's brilliant! Thank you! Will accept in 6 min, when StackOverflow lets me.

Comment: But, it looks like in this code you are making only a pointer to the head_node, not the head_node itself? Strange that one can then still access it.

Comment: @KeizerHarm The type of `*head_node` is `struct mylist_node`, i.e. an instance of the struct and not a pointer, so `sizeof(*head_node)` allocates enough bytes to hold an instance of that struct, and after the `malloc` call `head_node` points to that memory.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you have to allocate memory for your node, the way you were doing it, your node is a local variable on the stack which will likely get overwritten after the function exits.

```
void mylist_init(struct mylist* l)
{
    struct mylist_node *head_node = (struct mylist_node *)malloc(sizeof(struct mylist_node));
    head_node.data = 5; //First try
    l->head_pt = head_node;
};
```

Comment: Instead of `struct mylist_node *head_node = (struct mylist_node *)malloc(sizeof(struct mylist_node));`, code can use `struct mylist_node *head_node = malloc(sizeof *head_node);`  I hope you find this easier to code right, review and maintain.
    `